# JAVA 8 upgrade,only mvn clean install the tests are failing, any Idea?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, java-8

I upgraded my project form java 1.5 to java 1.8 and my tests pass in eclipse junit run and also pass when I run individual tests using "mvn  -Dtest=xxxx clean test" but when I run "mvn clean install" the tests are failing, any Idea ?

Comment: without the test code nor the related pom files it's impossible to help..

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to help answer your specific question without more detail, however here's some general guidance for things to check.

It seems likely that one or more of the individual tests are not properly initializing test fixtures or cleaning up after themselves. The earlier tests are changing the environment for the tests that follow. Tests that run after one of these polluting tests do not start with clean, properly initialized test data and they fail. When run individually, the test data is initialized and the formerly failing tests pass.

"Environment" could mean test class variables, cache, database, environment variables... etc.

When this situation happens, do not immediately assume that the tests are broken without a review of the code under test. Depending on what the code under test is doing, the failing test may be valid, pointing out a problem with initialization or proper cleanup in the code itself. For these cases, the tests have done their job!

Also, keep in mind that different JVMs can run tests in a different order - within classes, and between classes. Your test classes should not assume that tests will run in a specific order, thus each should be properly isolated from one another.

Comment: In my case changing surefire plugin version solved the issue